# Refreshing a datagridview that was added through designer

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, refresh

I've added a MySQL database through the datasources in Visual Studio. I've then dragged and dropped the table I want onto my form design and changed the layout to suit here and there.

I have a background worker that inserts data into the database occasionally using the MySQL connector. I've then been trying to refresh the datagridview to reflect the changes inserted into the database, but I can't get the form to update to show the new data.

Having read a few questions from people having similar trouble I've tried:

- Rebinding the data source as per this question [Refreshing a DataGridView after DB has changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322991/refreshing-a-datagridview-after-db-has-changed)
  and this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1cf64de-6e35-435c-943c-ed6e9b39525b/how-to-refresh-datagridview-component-using-designer?forum=csharpgeneral

  ```
   this.rfidDataGridView.DataSource = null;
   this.rfidDataGridView.Rows.Clear();
   this.rfidDataGridView.DataSource = this.rfidBindingSource;
  ```

  Which causes the datagridview to become a white square with an X in it
- Calling the reset methods as per here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f61k6akt.aspx

  ```
  this.mcbrideDataSet.Reset();
  this.rfidBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
  ```

  Which gives me a SystemOutOfRangeException at Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.getItem
- Refilling and refreshing

  ```
   this.rfidTableAdapter.Fill(this.mcbrideDataSet.rfid);



   this.rfidDataGridView.PerformLayout();
   this.rfidDataGridView.EndEdit();
   this.rfidDataGridView.Refresh();
   this.rfidDataGridView.Parent.Refresh();
  ```

I've tried a few other variations of all of the above.

As a lot of this data has been auto-generated by Visual Studio in Designer.cs I've tried following the data definitions and references to see if I could find anything useful in there, but I'm new enough to C# that I'm not getting anywhere. I can't see where the connection string is or where the dataSource is getting it's data. I've found it's declaration, but not where it's assigned values from the database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the grid view after it changes.

```
rfidDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation for DataGridView (and tried it in visual studio just in case) and I can't see a DataBind() method listed, there's a databindings property and a databindcompleted event, but no DataBind() method.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is what I'm using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

Comment: Hi David Macias, and welcome to Stack Overflow; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.